# 400 bad request with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a post request to the server,but it returns 400 error.
:[image]
this is react function

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const bookInstanceObject = {
    imprint: imprint,
  };

  axios
    .post('http://localhost:3001/catalog/bookinstance/create', bookInstanceObject)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

and this is the server side:

```js
router.post('/bookinstance/create', (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body;

  const bookInstance = new BookInstance({
    imprint: body.title,
  });

  bookInstance
    .save()
    .then(savedBook => {
      response.json(savedBook.toJSON());
    })
    .catch(error => next(error));
});
```

any idea ?

Comment: It seems like server thinks this is a GET request. Is there another part of the code where you do a get request to the same url?

Comment: Those are all HTTP Requests `router.get('/bookinstances', (request, response, next) => {...}                                                           router.get('/bookinstance/:id', (request, response, next) => {...}                                               router.put('/bookinstance/:id/update', (request, response, next) => {...}                            router.delete('/bookinstance/:id/delete', (request, response, next) => {...}`

Comment: @alizoubair they are wondering if you are making a `get` request from elsewhere, because the error is about a `get` request, not a `post` request that you have written. Unless axios is broken, which is unlikely.. I think. Also, really deeply look at the request/response in your dev tools. Check the headers. Make sure they are as expected. There could be a rogue redirect or something too up the chain before your error.

Answer (score 1):

## What I think is happening

The front end's `handleSubmit` function is POSTing to `/catalog/bookinstance/create`, while the server is expecting it to come to `/bookinstance/create`.

Simple typo, easy to miss when your stressing over it not working.

## How to fix?

Change the URLs to match.

Either:
change the front-end's POST url to `/bookinstance/create`,
or:
change the server's expected route to `router.post('/catalog/bookinstance/create',`

## Why is it a GET in the error log?

I don't *know* but I suspect that this error is about a GET request somewhere else in your code.

Please let us know in the comments if the error goes away with this fix. (Assuming my fix works)

Comment: Great catch! Who knows what that kind of post could do. Still curious why it's a get in logs..

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect that that error is reffering to a GET request somewhere else in his code. I'll update my answer.